# Expression has two different answers for an input?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was playing around with this expression earlier:

$$\frac{b^2t + bc^2t^2}{\sqrt {(b^4 + c^2b^2)t^4 + (b^4c^2 + b^2c^2)t^4)}}    $$

After a little algebra, I was able to manipulate it into the following equivalent expression:

$$\frac{b^2}{t\sqrt {(b^4 + c^2b^2) + (b^4c^2 + b^2c^2))}}  +  \frac{bc^2}{\sqrt {(b^4 + c^2b^2) + (b^4c^2 + b^2c^2))}} $$

Where b and c are constants, and t is in the input value. these two expressions are equal, but when t = 0, all the terms of the first expression are killed, returning 0, and yet the first term in the second expression blows up, returning infinity. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two terms are indeed the same, however the problem is already present in the first expression, but hiffen a bit. In the case $t=0$ your first expresiion becomes $\frac00$, which is not equal to $0$, but is not defined.

Comment: I see. Could I consider the "real" answer to be infinity then?

Comment: @Bookie
1. I do not recommend to do so.
2. If you consider it to be infinit. Be aware of the fact, that if $t<0$ it's actually negative infinite. That is you value depends on the choice of $t$. Unless all of your $t$ have the same sign it's really not defined.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.